# unicode for displaying formulas

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode

I am trying to complete my program in pyhton and would like to display a step by step formulas calculating a math problem. This includes a number of formulas that have subscripts and superscripts. I tried to use unicode but it looks like it is missing a lot of characters for sub/superscripts.

For example I would like to have the following formula x**(2/3) where (2/3) is a superscript or the following fbd where bd is a subscript. But it appears that there is no characters like "/" or "b". How can I get around this?

Thanks
K

Comment: Where are you trying to display your output? If it's in a terminal, you're probably going to be disappointed. You could try emitting LaTeX and render it in a browser using MathJAX.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I am using tkinter and trying to display full fomulas usinf TEXT widget and insert method. This is more graphical interface for users so they can understand the calculations steps.

Comment: @karlos Have you tried a mathematical font, or you can insert a character as image. If it's possible to use `Canvas` instead of `Text`, there you can place single character at any x/y offset from the ground line.

Comment: Unicode is not about formatting, and math formulas are about formatting. The (few) superscript/subscripts are included in Unicode for compatibility, but they should not be used (if possible). So for your task, you need an higher level: a markdown e. MathML/TeX/LaTeX, or directly HTML and various MarkDown (which uses MathML,Tex, LaTeX, according "plugin").